# Namespace "sf" has no member "Time"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I'm trying to write in a Scene Graph for a SFML project. I have the header and .cpp file and for the most part everything is fine except for this one error I keep getting. Namespace "sf" has no member "Time". I've looked up various forums and have tried referencing time in the header file and such but nothing has worked. Tips to get this working are very much appreciated.

//Header File

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class SceneNode : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable, private sf::NonCopyable
{

public:
      typedef std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> Ptr;
public:
     SceneNode();

void attachChild(Ptr child);
Ptr detachChild(const SceneNode& node);
void update(sf::Time dt);
sf::Vector2f getWorldPosition() const;
sf::Transform getWorldTransform() const;

private:
virtual void updateCurrent(sf::Time dt);
void updateChildren(sf::Time dt);

virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
virtual void drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
void drawChildren(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
private:
std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;
SceneNode* mParent;
};
```

//Main File

```
#include "SceneGraph.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

 using namespace std;

SceneNode::SceneNode()
: mChildren()
, mParent(nullptr)
{

}

void SceneNode::attachChild(Ptr child)
{
  child->mParent = this;
  mChildren.push_back(std::move(child));
}

SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::detachChild(const SceneNode& node)
{
  auto found = std::find_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), [&](Ptr& p { 
  return p.get() == &node; });
assert(found != mChildren.end());

   Ptr result = std::move(*found);
   result->mParent = nullptr;
   mChildren.erase(found);
  return result;
  }

void SceneNode::update(sf::Time dt)
{
    updateCurrent(dt);
    updateChildren(dt);
}

void SceneNode::updateCurrent(sf::Time)
{
     //Do nothing by default
}

void SceneNode::updateChildren(sf::Time dt)
{
      for_each(Ptr& child, mChildren)
         child->update(dt); 
}

void SceneNode::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
   //apply transform of current node
   states.transform *= getTransform(); 

   //draw node and children with changed transform
   drawCurrent(target, states);
   drawChildren(target, states);
}

void SceneNode::drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const
{
   //do nothing by default
}

void SceneNode::drawChildren(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    for_each(const Ptr& child, mChildren)
       child->draw(target, states);
}

 sf::Vector2f SceneNode::getWorldTransform() const
{
    sf::Transform transform = sf::Transform::Identity;
    for (const SceneNode* node = this; node != nullptr; node = node->mParent)
    transform = node->getTransform() * transform;

    return transform; 
 }
```

Comment: Missing an include? `Time` should be provided by the `sfml-system` SFML module.

Comment: @Asu That solved my issue, thank you!